# Условие для MediaPlayer

Tags: android-studio, mediaplayer, условия

Доброго времени суток!
В приложении при перелистывании картинки (ViewPager) идет музыка (на каждую картинку своя музыка), то есть, если открывается вторая картинка первая музыка должна выключиться,и начаться вторая, и т.д.
Сейчас при перелистывании, первая не выключаясь, включается вторая, потом третья и т.д.
Пробовала, но не могу додумать как сделать нормальное условие для MediaPlayerа. Помогите пожалуйста!
Вот код MainActivity.java:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static MediaPlayer mp=null;
ViewPager viewPager;
CustomSwipeAdapter adapter;
private int[] mAudio=new int[]{R.raw.sound_1,R.raw.sound_2,R.raw.sound_3};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mOnPageListener);

}
public OnPageChangeListener mOnPageListener=new OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        mp= MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,mAudio[position]);
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
};
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Они не выключаются, так как в коде не прописана остановка воспроизведения при смене вкладки. Нужно в `onPageSelected` добавить остановку воспроизведения в предыдущей открытой вкладке, или, чтобы не мучаться с вычислениями, просто все треки остановить, ведь далее в методе запустится нужный.